# Join Tables - include in result rows without data in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM orders o, customers c
WHERE o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Take all customers from table `customer`.

Count how much rows have column `status=1` in table `orders`, grouped by `customer_id`.

My `sql` works perfect if customer have at least one order in table `orders`(any status, even if all have status different by `1`).

But if there is an customer which have no order(does not depend status) in table `order`, it will not appear in result.

Let's say we have those 2 customers:

```
100 - C1 - 15 orders(7 have status 1)
101 - C2 - No orders
```

The Result will be:

```
100 | C1 | 7
```

How I can include `C2`?

```
100 | C1 | 7
101 | C2 | 0
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: It's `JOIN`- `LEFT JOIN`  (and music from 007 movies)

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

And, you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.id,  c.name, 
       COUNT(o.customer_id)
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.customer_id = c.id AND o.status = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join:

```
SELECT    id, name, COALESCE(sum_orders, 0)
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   customer_id, SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_orders
           FROM     orders
           GROUP BY customer_id) o ON c.id = o.customer_id
```